# sizeToFit clips the particular character for custom font

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, sizetofit

[image]

I'm not sure why? but using custom font with `NSAttributedString` when I `sizeToFit` the text it'll clip the particular character in string.

Here's the code sample:

```
NSString *appTitle = @"Hemang";
NSString *appQuote = @" My name last char is g";

NSString *mergedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",appTitle,appQuote];

UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.f, 80.f);
NSMutableAttributedString *firstLabelAttributes = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:mergedString];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrapStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.new;
paragrapStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[firstLabelAttributes addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrapStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [mergedString length])];

[firstLabelAttributes addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                             value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"NexaBold" size:50.f]
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [appTitle length])];

[firstLabelAttributes addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                             value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"NexaLight" size:10.f]
                             range:NSMakeRange([appTitle length]+1, [appQuote length])];

[label1 setNumberOfLines:2];
[label1 setAttributedText:firstLabelAttributes];
[self.view addSubview:label1];
[label1 sizeToFit];
label1.center = self.view.center;
```

## Update :

In my another test with normal

```
label1.text = @"Hemang"
[label1 sizeToFit];
```

> g clips

## Update 2:

Temporary work around is to increase some height after `sizeToFit` call.

```
CGRect frame = label1.frame
frame.size.height += 5;
label1.frame = frame;
```

It solved my problem but I really don't want this peace of patch.